# Save the selected data from dropdown retrieve from database

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have dropdown list that already retrieve value from database in my website. My problem is, I only can retrieve the data, but cannot save the data after user choose because i dont know where to put the code in my PHP
I want after user select the value from dropdown, user can save the data into the database

i am writing this PHP

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('glossary');

$sql = "SELECT categories FROM category_table";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='value'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['categories'] ."'>" . $row['categories'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

thanks in advance

Comment: you have to write update or insert query after select to save the data into database

Comment: you have to use FORM and SUBMIT button and script to save record ...

Comment: mysql_* functions have been deprecated. Use mysqli or PDO functions instead as these are more stable and secure: http://cz1.php.net/PDO

Comment: have a look here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/mysql_insert_php.htm

Comment: thank u, its work! but, how can i want to store the data with value, since i want to set the first data with value = 1 and next.

Comment: Better use select2 autocomplete and there's implemented ajax data sending...

Comment: @Michael u mean by using autocomplete i can set the value to store in database?

Comment: Sorry, little misunderstood, but you need form submit despite all.